# python routing issues with URL data

Tags: python, regex

How to read URL patterns with spaces that shoots off my targeted directories.
E.g.

```
url= http://example.appspot.com/abc%20asd  >>> abc asd
```

I am currently coding in python and there is something wrong with my regex. Thanks in advance!

```
class MainMain(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self,args):
        self.response.out.write('hello '+args)
def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainMain),('/(\w+)',MainMain)], debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Oftentimes such patterns are evaluated in order, with the first prefix matching being the one chosen.

Try moving your most general regex to the end:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/(\w+)',MainMain)],
    ('/', MainMain),
    debug=True)
```

Comment: Interesting.  I think this part is responsible for that behavior: [python/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py](http://code.google.com/codesearch#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/python/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py&q=WSGIApplication%20package:http://googleappengine%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=1163)

Comment: Hi, I realized that i left out the most important part of my question! I wanted to ask what should my regrex be if my url is something like this: 'http://example.appspot.com/asd asd' with the space being there, or replaced by %20, and the printed value is "asd asd". Thanks!

Comment: You'd need to add `\s` for whitespace, so something like `/([\w\s]+`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> url = 'http://example.appspot.com/abc%20asd'
>>> import urllib
>>> import urlparse
>>> urllib.unquote_plus(urlparse.urlparse(url)[2][1:])
'abc asd'
```

Comment: hihi thanks for helping me with this questions. However is it possible to make it more dynamic whereby the user will just type into the URL and i can print out whatever he has typed, including the spaces? Thanks!

Comment: Just replace `url` with whatever variable holds the user input.